# Can I make all setters invisible but one using Jackson?

Tags: java

I have an old class with many fields to be converted from/to JSON. The setters are not pure, so I make all setters invisible.

```
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

But there's one setter that actually set two fields, I need to make it visible.

```
private String a;

private transient String b;

public void setA(String a)
{
    this.a = a;
    this.b = convertFrom(a);
}
```

All setters are public. How can I make all setters invisible, but only one setter visible?

Comment: You are already doing smooth.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggested edit:** as  ExceptionHandler suggested, you can do ignore properties in two ways:

1. Class level
2. field level

As you don't want to do tedious field level task, you can do it by class level ignoring fields like below:

You can ignore all fields or fields specified using `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation at class level. Just don't mention the `field/s` for which you want to deserialize.
Like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "field1", "field2", "field3" })
public class YourClass{
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
   ...
}
```

Comment: A good **edit** to this answer will be if you can explain, different level on which you can ignore: `1) class level`  `2)field level`

Comment: Sorry. If I ignore setters, the fields will be ignored too, that's not what I want. So I edited the question, I just want setters invisible.

Comment: @lamplet, You have to choose which to ignore only, `@JsonIgnoreProperties({..})` . Not the one you want to keep.